# wiki site doesn't appear in tfs

Tags: tfs

Just now I've set up a new wiki page in our TFS, but it doesn't show up by another computer/colleague. What could be the reason?

Comment: You mean on the TFS Sharepoint site?

Comment: Have you checked permissions to ensure that the other colleague has permissions to access it?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet it's security within SharePoint. Whenever adding users to a TFS project, they must be added to not only TFS, but also the SharePoint site and SQL reporting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your changes aren't checked in yet.  Click on "Team Wiki" then select "Home" and see if an option to "Check In" is available.